# Default search in Google Chrome locked to smartsputnik.ru

Tags: browser

Default search in Google Chrome locked by smartsputnik.ru. I am receiving the following message:
This setting is enforced by your administrator

I have tried deleting all the entries in registry and also resetting and reinstalling Chrome but this did not help. I have also tried the proposed solution someone else here found that worked - No success for me. I still cannot rid my machine of smartsputnik.ru search engine.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACCHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
2.Delete file - C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol

I have run various malware executers but nothing will help regain control of my Google search default.

Are there any other suggestions or useful ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This Malware SUCKS!!! I got the same thing and it took me 9 hour to track it down and kill it!!!

I tried everything that you tried. But the thing that worked was.....
I went into the registry and clicked CTRL + F or the edit tab and Find. I then typed in google and went through EVERY google registry file, one by one by using the F3 key to Find Next. About my 20th one in I found a peculiar path to chrome for the **value data**. I think the path to it was **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/ChromeHTML/shell/open/command** and I deleted everything after chrome.exe in the value data, but since I tried many things I could be wrong, I'm about 90% sure that that was the correct path. It had something like **C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --%"** ,for its value data.
I don't remember exactly the ending symbols but EVERY other path that I found had C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe,0 . Notice that it is a ,0 and not " --%". I then right clicked the name and deleted the " --%" garbage.

I also went to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes/LowRegistry/audio/PolicyConfig/PropertyStore/c44b5619_0** and deleted everything in the value data. It had a bunch of lines of unknown garbage and a weird chrome.exe file path.

After doing these things AND running several malware programs, which didn't do much, I now had the ability to delete smartsputnik.ru as a permanent search engine. AND MAN WAS IT SATISFYING!!!!!!!!

If you have any questions I will be happy to help because this was the most frustrating malware I have ever had to deal with, and I have been at this a long time.

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Software/ChromeHTML/shell/open/command Sorry I forgot to include "Software" in the first registry path.

Comment: I also turned off inheriting parent permissions on the Google Chrome shortcut and executable. Because there was a weird user that had permission to edit Google Chrome. It had {a bunch of number here} in its name. Here is a link that helped me with permissions. http://www.ehow.com/how_8494584_turn-off-permission-inheritance.html

Comment: Excellent.  This worked for me.  Smartsputnik has now gone and I've regained Google as my default search engine.

Thanks you for sharing.